# get_users() with include AND exclude

Tags: php, wordpress

I am retrieving a list of users that are in an array (id's only), this array represents connections between users. The idea is to display X users and hide the rest, so users with avatars set is a priority.

This is what I have that is not working correctly:

```
// Get all connection id's with avatars
$members_with_photos = get_users(array('meta_key' => 'profile_avatar', 'include' => $connections));

// Shuffle them
shuffle($members_with_photos);

// Add the the all_members list
foreach($members_with_photos as $member_with_photo){
    $all_members[] = $member_with_photo->ID;
}

// Get all connection id's without avatars
$members_without_photos = get_users(array('exclude' => $all_members, 'include' => $connections));

// Shuffle them
shuffle($members_without_photos);

// Also add them to the list
foreach($members_without_photos as $member_without_photos){
    $all_members[] = $member_without_photos->ID;
}
```

The problem is that $members_without_photos is filled with every user out of the $connections array. So that means the include is prioritised above exclude.

What needs to happen is that get_users() needs to look for users from connections, but exclude the ones that already are found (with avatars) so that the users without avatars will appear last in the $all_members array.

The way I fix it now is use array_unique() on the $all_members array after, but I think that is more of a dirty fix. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23228

Comment: Doing array_unique on $all_members is as good as it's going to get until they update this..

Comment: @AlexanderKuzmin's link to the WP ticket is your answer. There is no way other than to build your own version of `get_users()` (e.g. `gideons_get_users()` and calling it instead). Potentially you could use PHP's [override_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) to replace the built in WP function with one of your own where the patch in the ticket is included, but I am not sure I would 100% support such solution because it is only slightly less forward-compatibility-breaking work than modifying *wp-includes/user.php* directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_diff` and calculate the include list in PHP. This should give the behaviour that you are looking for. The code with the `array_diff` added in:

```
// Get all connection id's with avatars
$members_with_photos = get_users(array('meta_key' => 'profile_avatar', 'include' => $connections));

// Shuffle them
shuffle($members_with_photos);

// Add the the all_members list
foreach($members_with_photos as $member_with_photo){
    $all_members[] = $member_with_photo->ID;
}

// Get all connection id's without avatars
$members_without_photos_ids = array_diff($connections, $all_members);

$members_without_photos = get_users(array('include' => $members_without_photos_ids));

// Shuffle them
shuffle($members_without_photos);

// Also add them to the list
foreach($members_without_photos as $member_without_photos){
    $all_members[] = $member_without_photos->ID;
}
```